# Want to create user-accessible form in Axapta that uses SQL with a substring function

Tags: sql, forms, substring, report, axapta

I have some sqlserver sql that due to data can't be modified, which I currently run from Sqlserver. It uses a substring function. I want to stop running it from Sqlserver and create a user-accessible form in which the user enters a date and the script goes off and does it's thing and returns row data to the user.

Not overly familar with X++. I've looked at reports, querys, jobs, statement classes, not sure what's the correct path.

Below is the sql code.

```
'
select a.description,b.itemid, c.phantom,a.createddatetime,a.createdby
from sysdatabaselog A

   inner join
   bomversion B
   on substring(a.description,1,11) = b.bomid

   inner join
   inventtable C
   on b.itemid = c.itemid

where (table_ = 18 and logtype=1)
and a.CREATEDDATETIME > '2018-03-01'     <-------- this would be user-supplied on the form 
and c.phantom=1          
'
```

Comment: Could you give us an idea what an answer to your question would look like? Currently, it is hard to tell what you are asking and what you expect from an answer. Also consider taking a look at [ask].

Comment: Thanks for asking. It would look like a display form with a field that the user would type a  date into. The code would then pull in all applicable data past that user-supplied date. I feel there's several ways to skin this cat, i'm primarily looking for a plan with steps generally in the correct order. First A, then do B, then C etc.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to accomplish is actually pretty high-level in AX and requires a several different dev techniques to accomplish it. I'm not going to do the entire thing for you, but I'll get you started and tell you what you need to do. These screenshots are from AX2012.

To accomplish the `SUBSTRING()` you need an AX `View` + `String computed column`.

For your view, you'll want an AX `Query` object to contain your joins OR you can just do a simple view on the `BOMVersion` table and then work against that.

Here's an example `View` and `String computed column` and the method for the computed column. I just used `SalesTable` and `SalesId` as the sample.

```
public static server str compSubStrSalesName()
{
    str result;

    result = strFmt("SUBSTRING(%1, 1, 5)",
                SysComputedColumn::returnField(identifierStr(SubStringExample), // The name of your view
                                               identifierStr(SalesTable_1), // The name of your view's datasource
                                               identifierStr(SalesId) // The name of the field
                                               )
    );

    return result;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is mostly new to me so let me give it a shot!

Comment: Apparently there's no such thing as string computed columns in AX2009, surprising.

Comment: @KWMKWM if you're using 2009, perhaps you can add a custom column to `BOMVersion` and then whenever data is inserted, you populate that column via `x++` using `subStr(...)`? Or you can just use logic with `x++` to find the same data.

Comment: Talked to the powers that be and they were unenthused about the new column or changing the data in the existent one. Looks like I'd have to go with the latter and create a form and code etc.

Comment: A new column doesn't need to be visible to the users...sometimes that confuses them. You would just disable editing, make it not visible, and then put a couple lines of code after the `super()` call in the `.insert()` method and that would give you the column you need. Either solution works though.

Comment: I think the new column you suggest is best, but management...so doing the substring is required so far but I'll have to experiment. I hear that's impossible in AX2009 but don't really see how, the bug in the soup is the a.description in sysdatabaselog in which the bom id is stored joined to the part number like IB022015236, 2451604, and I just need the front part (IB022015236) to join to table BOMVERSION (b). Therefor the need for substring at all.

Comment: Personally I'd push back just because all other options are worse. You can use an AX temporary table and insert the values using AX function `subStr(...)`, then join to it. That's just a waste of resources and is slower.

Comment: They said nada again. Yet another thing came up so I get to backburner this for a while, that'll give me some time to learn AX at least to create a form that asks for the date and I guess feeds that temp table for reporting.